Why does it display a 404 error when the file is available?
I created a file at the root of my Wordpress site with the following code:
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';

When I launch the file via the browser, I get a 404 error.
If I add an echo to the file, for example :
echo “ok”;

I no longer get a 404 error.
Why is this?
Thanks

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';  // This loads the WordPress environment without triggering the theme or front-end routing

 // Now you can access WordPress functions
echo "ok";

 // You can also perform WordPress operations, for example:
   $post = get_post(1); // Fetch post with ID 1
    echo $post->post_title;

   //if this is not what you're looking for please clarify why do you want to use wp-blog-header.php

